# GNU gdb how to show source file name and lines of a symbol

Tags: c, gdb, gnu

when use GNU gdb to debug a c process.

list command will print the lines but not telling me the file name.

set breakpoints can display all the line and file info I want but I don't want to set a breakpoint and have to disable or delete it.

```
(gdb) b oyss_funtion
Breakpoint 13 at 0x8049130: file main.c, line 119.
```

Is there a gdb command or settings can show me the file line info of a function(symbol) without setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: Besides other interesting things the `bt` (short for `backtrace`) command provides this info.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `info line` command.

```
info line oyss_function
```

For example, assume the file `test.c` contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, invoking `info line main` in GDB gets:

```
(gdb) info line main
Line 4 of "test.c" starts at address 0x400498 <main> and ends at 0x40049c <main+4>.
```

Comment: I'm getting `No line number information available for address 0x48a746 <main>`. Why would this happen? Edit: Oops, needed to compile with `-g` in GCC.

Comment: This answer only show the file name. To get the full path see this answer below a linked question: [c++ - Identify source file name for a symbol in gdb debugger - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827608/5267751).