# Identify source file name for a symbol in gdb debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am debugging an application based on multiple C++ shared libraries in `gdb` on Ubuntu 18.04 and
want to find the source code (or at least the name of the shared library or C++ namespace) of a symbol called `TRUE`.

<del>All code has been compiled with `-g3 -O0 -Wall`.</del>

**Edit:** I have "only" the debug symbols available for shared libraries and the application code is compiled with `-g3 -O0 -Wall`.

Here is what I know about the symbol in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) ptype TRUE
type = enum {FALSE, TRUE}
(gdb) whatis TRUE
type = enum {...}
(gdb) info line TRUE
(gdb)
```

How can I find out who defined the `enum` of my `TRUE` symbol`?

There is a similar question but the answer does not give the expected output (but empty, see log above): https://stackoverflow.com/a/20771062

**Edit:** I am one step further (but still the full path is missing for such a common kind of file name):

```
(gdb) python print(gdb.lookup_symbol("TRUE")[0].symtab)
api.cpp
```

Comment: Once gdb gave the info it's an 'enum {FALSE, TRUE}' you can `grep` through the sources/headers.

Comment: Yes, this does work and that is what I am doing currently but it takes some time to find the symbol and for some shared libraries I have only installed the debug symbols (without the source code) so I had to install the source code too.

Answer (score 4):

I have found it finally! Python is the solution, the `gdb` object within Python does offer more detailed information than the pure native `gdb` commands:

```
(gdb) python print(gdb.lookup_symbol("TRUE")[0].symtab.fullname())
/media/devmount/dev/R/Rcpp/src/api.cpp
```

For details see the documentation: https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbol-Tables-In-Python.html#Symbol-Tables-In-Python

**Edit:** I have found a `gdb` command for that but it seems not to work in my case:

```
(gdb) set print symbol-filename on
(gdb) show print symbol-filename
Printing of source filename and line number with <symbol> is on.
(gdb) ptype TRUE
type = enum {FALSE, TRUE}
```

Comment: Just wondering if you got any further with your python/gdb adventure. I just want to find which c file a certain symbol is in even if that file context hasn't yet been loaded. Currently I'm running emacs in parallel and grepping for the function but I'm thinking there must be an "in gdb" option to find a c function symbol.

Comment: @RichieHH My python code in the answers seem to work only for loaded (or statically linked) libraries, If "file context hasn't been loaded' means the library is not yet dynamically loaded: I have never tried to find a symbol in `gdb` **before** it has been loaded, sorry. And I can hardly imagine that `gdb` could find the file since all debug information for the symbol is missing then.

Comment: Remark: instead of `lookup_symbol`, [`lookup_global_symbol` or `lookup_static_symbol` etc.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols-In-Python.html#Symbols-In-Python) can be used depends on the scope.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if GDB exposes this information. It is recorded in the DWARF data, so you can dump it using `dwarfdump` or `eu-readelf -w`. The latter is part of [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) and it produces output like this:

```
DWARF section [11] '.debug_macro' at offset 0xac:

 Offset:             0x0
 Version:            4
 Flag:               0x2 (debug_line_offset)
 Offset length:      4
 .debug_line offset: 0x0

 #include offset 0x0
 start_file 0, [1] file.c
  start_file 31, [2] /usr/include/stdc-predef.h
   #include offset 0x0
  end_file
  #define FALSE 0, line 1 (indirect)
  #define TRUE 1, line 2 (indirect)
 end_file
```

Assuming that `file.c` contains:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
```

Given the nested structure of DWARF, this is not something that can easily be processed by tools like grep, though.

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately `dwarfdump` says `DW_AT_name TRUE` and `readelf` says `<bb1d> DW_AT_name : (indirect string, offset: 0x22afa): TRUE`. BTW: Do you really mean `eu-readelf` (I couldn't find that, just `readelf`)?

Comment: THX, my tired eyes haven't seen your `elfutils` link. I could finally find the symbol and file (even with the line number) in the output of `eu-readelf` but my example symbol (`TRUE`) is matching many lines in the output and I have to lookup the file via another search for a file number: `decl_file (data1) 98 | decl_line (data1) 35 |  98 ... api.cpp`

Comment: Sorry, for confusing you, there wasn't a link before, just the project name … (I assume it was reasonably common knowledge, sorry.) Glad you found a GDB-based solution that suites your needs.